# How to get HuggingFace tokenizers to recognize newline?

Tags: python, tokenize, huggingface

I've been using HuggingFace tokenizers, and it seems that when I process a string with a newline character, it ignores it and treats it like a space character. I want to create my own language model, and I believe having the ability to generate structured paragraphs would be useful.

```
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.models import WordPiece
bert_tokenizer = Tokenizer(WordPiece(unk_token="[UNK]"))

from tokenizers import normalizers
from tokenizers.normalizers import NFD, StripAccents
bert_tokenizer.normalizer = normalizers.Sequence([NFD(), StripAccents()])

from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import BertPreTokenizer
bert_tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = BertPreTokenizer()

from tokenizers.processors import TemplateProcessing
bert_tokenizer.post_processor = TemplateProcessing(
    single="[CLS] $A [SEP]",
    pair="[CLS] $A [SEP] $B:1 [SEP]:1",
    special_tokens=[
        ("[CLS]", 1),
        ("[SEP]", 2),
    ],
)

from tokenizers.trainers import WordPieceTrainer
trainer = WordPieceTrainer(special_tokens=["[UNK]", "[CLS]", "[SEP]", "[PAD]", "[MASK]"])
file = 'input.txt'
bert_tokenizer.train([file], trainer)

from tokenizers import decoders
bert_tokenizer.decoder = decoders.WordPiece()

output = bpe_tokenizer.encode("This is the first line.\nThis is the second line.")
print(bpe_tokenizer.decode(output.ids))
# Should read as:
# This is the first line.
# This is the second line
#
# Instead I get:
# This is the first line. This is the second line.
```

I've tried other tokenizer models like BPE, but they have the issue of merging tokens together. I found the WordPiece tokenizer to produce more legible outputs, but I would like to generate paragraphs or script lines as potential outputs.